# Best win32 compiled scripting language?

Tags: windows, compiler-construction, scripting

What is the best compilable scripting language for Win32?  I prefer .EXE's because I don't want to install the runtime on the servers first (my company administrates many via remote), but I need to be able to do things like NTFS permissions and (if possible) APIs over the network.

There was a small Perl which appeared to be able to do most of this, but it does not seem to have been updated/developed in quite a while.  I have wondered about Lua, but I don't know if it has everything I need yet (and don't want to hunt through fifty library sites trying to find out).  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you considered using an EXE maker? For example, you can code in Python and use [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org) to create a standalone EXE that runs anywhere (it actually packages Python into the exe, so you don't have to install the runtime).

Comment: py2exe is great...except when it comes to threading...

Answer (score 4):

Ruby is my scripting language of choice.

Try [RubyScript2Exe](http://www.erikveen.dds.nl/rubyscript2exe/).

Comment: That's interesting.  Does Ruby do Win32 as thoroughly as Python?

Answer (score 2):

A scripting language is, almost by definition, not compiled into a standalone executable. So maybe you need to restate your intentions or give some indication about what kind of program you want to create.

C# is a powerful language that compiles to .EXE and allows you to interface with pretty much anything (through native p/invoke calls, if necessary). A basic but very usable Visual Studio for C# can be downloaded for free from the Microsoft website. The .NET runtime is installed on most systems nowadays.

Comment: Actually `C#` compiles to `bytecode`, it just has a compiled stub. Which is a lot like py2exe or PAR (perl).

Comment: I know, but it still compiles to .EXE. I never said that the .EXE contained only native code ;)

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/) ?

It is a scripting language, and you can quickly transform a script into an exe...

Answer (score 1):

At OSCON 2005, I heard Damien Conway say "the only thing better than Perl is something that works well, even if it's not written in Perl."

It's good advice.  Instead of looking for the *best* language that can be compiled to an .EXE, worry a lot more about writing it in *a* language that can be compiled to an .EXE.  Use whatever works.  Just remember that the quality of your programming matters infinitely more than what language you use.

That said, I like py2exe.  YMMV.  Good luck!